# Stuck trying to install VBox Ext Pack in Parrot Sec and How to make Term remember Commands?

Tags: linux, terminal, virtualbox

Ok, so I have a couple problems.  I am trying to install VBOX Ext pack in Parrot Sec however everytime I go to install it, it asks for the Admin password.  Well I am the admin and I enter my password and it says incorrect password?

My other question relates to the terminal in Parrot.  It is a bash terminal.  In kali when you type a command it remembers it and when you go to type another command it has a history and kind of pops up and you can scroll through previous commands using the arrow key.  Does anyone know how I would make this work in Parrot.  Is there a script somewhere?

Comment: 1. Are you part of the group wheel/sudo? 2. I answered your question on your other post.

Comment: Check if it's really bash you're running, and check whether history is enabled. See `man bash` for how to use history in bash.